# How to I create Recycler View with Retrofit + Moshi

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

I am trying to add recycler view to the json response.

I am able to successfull print the data I get through response in toast but I am not sure how to pass it along the RecyclerView adapter.  Most of them talk about is Gson Converter and none on Moshi

I have searched internet for a while but I was helpless.

I am wondering how do I pass the pass the data from the myactivity(OrderHistoryActivity) to the RecyclerViewAdapter(OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter).

Here is my Code

**OrderHistoryActivity**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tesmachino.saycure.Auth.TokenManager;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderHistoryGet;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderHistoryResponse;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.network.ApiService;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.network.RetrofitBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class OrderHistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ApiService service;
    TokenManager tokenManager;

    Call<OrderHistoryResponse> call;
    private static final String TAG = "OrderHistoryActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_history);

        tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
        service = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManager);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        call = service.orderHistory();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<OrderHistoryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OrderHistoryResponse> call, Response<OrderHistoryResponse> response) {
                Toast.makeText(OrderHistoryActivity.this, "" + response.body().getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<OrderHistoryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(OrderHistoryActivity.this, "Please Try again after some time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderHistoryResponse;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;


public class OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_order_history, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView order_id;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            order_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_id);

        }
    }
}
```

**OrderHistoryResponse**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory;

import com.squareup.moshi.Json;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderHistoryResponse {
    @Json(name = "data")
    private List<OrderHistoryGet> data = null;

    public List<OrderHistoryGet> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<OrderHistoryGet> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("data", data).toString();
    }


}
```

**OrderHistoryGet**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory;

import com.squareup.moshi.Json;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderHistoryGet {

    @Json(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Json(name = "payment_callback_id")
    private Integer paymentCallbackId;
    @Json(name = "payment_orderid")
    private Integer paymentOrderid;
    @Json(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;
    @Json(name = "service_type_id")
    private Integer serviceTypeId;
    @Json(name = "number_of_cameras")
    private Integer numberOfCameras;
    @Json(name = "camera_type")
    private Integer cameraType;
    @Json(name = "dvr_channel")
    private Integer dvrChannel;
    @Json(name = "paid_amount")
    private Integer paidAmount;
    @Json(name = "is_paid")
    private Integer isPaid;
    @Json(name = "status")
    private Integer status;
    @Json(name = "deleted_at")
    private Object deletedAt;
    @Json(name = "created_at")
    private String createdAt;
    @Json(name = "updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;
    @Json(name = "service_assign_status")
    private List<OrderHistoryServiceAssign> serviceAssignStatus = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getPaymentCallbackId() {
        return paymentCallbackId;
    }

    public void setPaymentCallbackId(Integer paymentCallbackId) {
        this.paymentCallbackId = paymentCallbackId;
    }

    public Integer getPaymentOrderid() {
        return paymentOrderid;
    }

    public void setPaymentOrderid(Integer paymentOrderid) {
        this.paymentOrderid = paymentOrderid;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public Integer getServiceTypeId() {
        return serviceTypeId;
    }

    public void setServiceTypeId(Integer serviceTypeId) {
        this.serviceTypeId = serviceTypeId;
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfCameras() {
        return numberOfCameras;
    }

    public void setNumberOfCameras(Integer numberOfCameras) {
        this.numberOfCameras = numberOfCameras;
    }

    public Integer getCameraType() {
        return cameraType;
    }

    public void setCameraType(Integer cameraType) {
        this.cameraType = cameraType;
    }

    public Integer getDvrChannel() {
        return dvrChannel;
    }

    public void setDvrChannel(Integer dvrChannel) {
        this.dvrChannel = dvrChannel;
    }

    public Integer getPaidAmount() {
        return paidAmount;
    }

    public void setPaidAmount(Integer paidAmount) {
        this.paidAmount = paidAmount;
    }

    public Integer getIsPaid() {
        return isPaid;
    }

    public void setIsPaid(Integer isPaid) {
        this.isPaid = isPaid;
    }

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Object getDeletedAt() {
        return deletedAt;
    }

    public void setDeletedAt(Object deletedAt) {
        this.deletedAt = deletedAt;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public List<OrderHistoryServiceAssign> getServiceAssignStatus() {
        return serviceAssignStatus;
    }

    public void setServiceAssignStatus(List<OrderHistoryServiceAssign> serviceAssignStatus) {
        this.serviceAssignStatus = serviceAssignStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("id", id).append("paymentCallbackId", paymentCallbackId).append("paymentOrderid", paymentOrderid).append("customerId", customerId).append("serviceTypeId", serviceTypeId).append("numberOfCameras", numberOfCameras).append("cameraType", cameraType).append("dvrChannel", dvrChannel).append("paidAmount", paidAmount).append("isPaid", isPaid).append("status", status).append("deletedAt", deletedAt).append("createdAt", createdAt).append("updatedAt", updatedAt).append("serviceAssignStatus", serviceAssignStatus).toString();
    }

}
```

**apiService**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure.network;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderHistoryResponse;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;


public interface ApiService {

    @GET("order-history")
    Call<OrderHistoryResponse> orderHistory();

}
```

**RetrofitBuilder**

```
package com.tesmachino.saycure.network;

import com.facebook.stetho.okhttp3.StethoInterceptor;

import com.tesmachino.saycure.Auth.TokenManager;
import com.tesmachino.saycure.BuildConfig;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitBuilder {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.11/say-cure-web/public/api/";
//    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://saycure.tesmachino.xyz/api/";

    private final static OkHttpClient client = buildClient();
    private final static Retrofit retrofit = buildRetrofit(client);

    private static OkHttpClient buildClient() {

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()

                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                        Request request = chain.request();

                        Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                                .addHeader("Connection", "close");

                        request = builder.build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);

                    }
                });

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private static Retrofit buildRetrofit(OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static <T> T createService(Class<T> service) {

        return retrofit.create(service);
    }

    public static <T> T createServiceWithAuth(Class<T> service, TokenManager tokenManager) {

        OkHttpClient newClient = client.newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request request = chain.request();

                Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();

                if (tokenManager.getToken().getAccessToken() != null) {
                    builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenManager.getToken().getAccessToken());
                }

                request = builder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);

            }
        }).build();

        Retrofit newRetroFit = retrofit.newBuilder().client(newClient).build();
        return newRetroFit.create(service);
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Any Help on this would be great appreciation.  If my question is not clear please do let me know, I would be glad to rephrase it. Please explain me how it worked on the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your `OrderHistoryActivity` activity take RecyclerView in XML and create object in `OrderHistoryActivity.java`.
- create `item.xml` file 
  **Note: It is require becuase you are using `activity_order_history` (OrderHistoryActivity xml file) for viewHolder which is wrong.**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

- Now Modify OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter.java as:

```java
package com.tesmachino.saycure;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.tesmachino.saycure.entities.OrderHistory.OrderHistoryResponse;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;


public class OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 private List<OrderHistoryGet> data;


  public OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter(List<OrderHistoryGet> data){
          this.data = data;
   }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item.xml, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

      OrderHistoryGet obj = data.get(position);

      holder.order_id.setText(obj.getId()+"");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView order_id;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            order_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderid);

        }
    }
}
```

Now in `onResponse` method  do this.

```java
   ....

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<OrderHistoryResponse> call, Response<OrderHistoryResponse> response) {
                Toast.makeText(OrderHistoryActivity.this, "" + response.body().getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter adapter = new OrderHistoryRecyclerAdapter(response.body().getData());

      //This recyclerView object should create before,  like      findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewIdinXML)


         RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        ((LinearLayoutManager) manager).setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
         recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }
        });
    }

   ...
```

Thats it.

Comment: Thaks for the write up. I appreciate it. I am getiing error: cannot find symbol method getContext() in OrderHistoryActivity - onResponse . Any idea how could it be fixed

Comment: While going throught the documentation of RecyclerView.LayoutManager, it says deprecated. Any other alternatives

Comment: Thanks a lot. I replaced the getContext() with getApplicationContext()